# Pygame, no ScreenUpdates via pygame.display.update(rect_list) after game was moved to background?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pygame, raspberry-pi

Using: pygame 2.5.2 (SDL 2.28.2, Python 3.10.12) on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS

My pygame app, which is running with the `.set_mode` flags `FULLSCREEN` and `NOFRAME`, is updating the screen via `pygame.display,update(rect_list)`.
After moving the app into the background and getting it back in front the screen isn't updated anymore.

Using `pygame.display,update()` or `pygame.display.flip()` will keep the updates running.

This behaviour is not showing without the above posted flags.

Runnnig the same code on a RaspberryPI isn't showing this behaviour

Is this behaviour known/correct?

Sample code showing the above behaviour:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import (
    K_ESCAPE,
    QUIT,
    KEYDOWN,
    MOUSEBUTTONDOWN,
    NOFRAME,
    FULLSCREEN
)
pygame.init()

pygame.font.init()
pygame.event.set_allowed([QUIT, KEYDOWN,MOUSEBUTTONDOWN])

flags = NOFRAME | FULLSCREEN
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0,0),flags) 
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

....
blit_Sequence=[]
blit_Sequence.extend(((scopeA, (scopeLeft,scopeATop)),(scopeB, 
(scopeLeft,scopeBTop))))
....
#some code to do intial drawings

pygame.display.flip() #display the initial screen contents

#The GameLoop starts here!
while running:
    
    #some drawings on the scopeA and scopeB like:
    nextX = nextX +1
    scopeA.fill((13,11,0), special_flags=pygame.BLEND_RGB_SUB)
    scopeB.blit(secScope,(nextX,0),((nextX,0),(nextWidth+1,scopeHeight)))
    .....
    scopeRect=screen.blits(blit_Sequence,1)
    scopeRect.extend((scopeLabelA_rect,scopeLabelB_rect))

    pygame.display.update(scopeRect)
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have added sample code in the initial post.